# jelly-bean video intent not returning after capture

Tags: android, video-capture, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-camera-intent

I am working with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running Android 4.1.1 (Jelly-bean), I recently upgraded from 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

I used the ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE action of MediaStore to capture videos in my activity.

```
Uri uriSavedVideo = Uri.fromFile(output);

Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); 
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedVideo);

startActivityForResult(videoIntent, CAMERA_VIDEO_CAPTURE_MODE);
```

This code returned to my main intent once the video was recorded and the "Save" button was pressed from the save/discard options available in ICS.

After my upgrade the video action has certainly changed and even after successfully capturing a video the intent does not return to my calling intent, my users and I are having to press the back button to come to my calling intent.

Any ideas or suggestions on how this can be avoided.  The expected behaviour is that once a video has been captured, it should return to the calling intent.